# How to select the last values from a pandas series using timedelta?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, series

I've a pandas series with timestamps as indices and floats as values

```
pd.Series(
    data=[150.0, 151.0, ...],
    index=[
        datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 24, 15, 53, 54, 532325, tzinfo=None, fold=0),
        datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 24, 16, 1, 7, 896288, tzinfo=None, fold=0),
        ...]
)
```

resulting in:

```
2020-01-24T15:53:54.532325    150.0
2020-01-24T16:01:07.896288    151.0
2020-01-24T16:01:10.862610    152.0
2020-01-24T16:01:13.407573    149.0
2020-01-24T16:33:59.985246    148.0
2020-01-24T16:34:06.411970    150.0
```

**How can I select the last values with their corresponding indices via a timedelta w.r.t. the most recent timedelta values in seconds**? For e.g. the series given and a timedelta of 2 seconds I'd expect the subset of the series

```
2020-01-24T16:33:59.985246    148.0
2020-01-24T16:34:06.411970    150.0
```

This should be equivalent to what I should get with `timestamped_intensity['2020-01-24T16:33:59.9852462':'2020-01-24T16:34:06.411970']` via [indexing by time](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.11-working-with-time-series.html#Pandas-Time-Series:-Indexing-by-Time).

Comment: No, he needs the last 2 records ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### **UPDATE**

**by elements** [`Series.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html)

```
s.sort_index().tail(2)

#date
#2020-01-24 16:33:59.985246    148.0
#2020-01-24 16:34:06.411970    150.0
#Name: value, dtype: float64
```

**By seconds**

**we calculate the time difference in the index and index when the cumulative sum and semnor that 2**

```
n = 2
s[s.sort_index(ascending = False)
   .index
   .to_series()
   .diff().abs()
   .dt.total_seconds()
   .cumsum()
   .fillna(0)
   .lt(n)]
```

Comment: or (more flexible) ....iloc[-2:, :]    Also consider making a copy to avoid by surprises. So, .copy() after the result.

Comment: I'm using a pandas Series, no pandas DataFrame.

Comment: I'd like to index by timedelta, not by # elements... I tried to improve the question.

Comment: check by seconds

Comment: Works, but my solution is more flexible cause its possible to define the timedelta in days, microseconds, etc. as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not nice but works for me:

```
timedelta_in_seconds = 2
most_recent_timestamp = timestamped_intensity.sort_index().index[-1]
timestamped_intensity[most_recent_timestamp - datetime.timedelta(seconds=timedelta_in_seconds):most_recent_timestamp]
```

Comment: you don't need `tail`, only `most_recent_timestamp = timestamped_intensity.sort_index().index[-1]`

Comment: Nope, I think I need it. Otherwise I get not what I expect.

Comment: I am sure, check it

Comment: If I don't use `tail(1)` I get the first and not the last timestamp

Comment: `most_recent_timestamp = timestamped_intensity.sort_index().index[-1]`

Comment: Right, even better.

Comment: The `sort_index()` is awkward... If the index is not sorted, then the indexing will not work, since it returns a range of rows, so it depends on it being sorted. So I'd just reword it to say "Assuming the index is sorted..." or perhaps "First make sure your index is sorted..." then continue to the answer. Also, you don't need an interval at the right, `timestamped_intensity[most_recent_timestamp - pd.to_timedelta('2s'):]` is enough.

Comment: Shouldn't ensure [`sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) exactly that the series is sorted according to datetimes? Shouldn't be indexing afterwards with `.index[-1]` just be fine?

Comment: I dislike specifying the timedelta as string with `'2s'` cause it does not allow to put the logic into a function and specify timedeltas in a flexible way.